# Using Font Awesome with Petite Vue

Tags: html, frontend, font-awesome, petite-vue

I am trying to use Font Awesome with [Petite Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue). As it is a lightweight version of Vue with no build step, I cannot use the Font Awesome Vue Component.

I am using a Font Awesome Pro Kit (web fonts to avoid CORS issues) and importing Font Awesome and Petite Vue in a `<script>` tag.

However, when inside a `v-for` loop, I cannot get the Font Awesome icon to display.

`<i class="fa fa-thin fa-{{ item.icon }}"></i>`

It works fine outside the `v-for` loop, even if still inside a `v-scope` tag and hard-coding an icon name works too. It also works as expected if not using Petite Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `v-bind` (aka. `:`) directive to evaluate an expression and use it as a class. It can see the loop variable(s) in a `v-for` loop.

```
<i class="fa fa-thin" :class="'fa'+item.icon"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by using `v-effect` to dynamically add the icon name class.

`<i class="fa fa-thin" v-effect="$el.classList.add('fa-' + item.icon)"></i>`